# Node.JS and Jquery - typeError createWindow is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to play around with node.js and send a xmlhttp request to a server from my server.js file using node.js server object.

I have defined the following at the beginning of my .js file:

```
var http = require('http');
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var $ = require('jquery');
```

When I try to run the .js file using the nodejs console I get the following error:

require(...).jsdom(...).createWindow is not a function

Is there something obvious I am missing?

I have looked around for answers but got no further.

Comment: Does jsdom have a createWindow function?

Comment: Would need to see more of your code to be able to help any further.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.

It seemed that this was a known bug in an older version of jquery. Reinstalling the newest version of Jquery in node.js solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `package.json` file and see under the `dependencies`, which version of jQuery you are using. Chances are you are using 1.7.4

I faced the same issue with this older version. Move to Jquery 3.2.1 to resolve it.

When your do,

```
npm install jQuery
```

It installs the old version.

On doing

```
npm install jquery
```

It installs the newer version.

The difference is only the  uppercase Q.